pnp/spfx-property-controls Not working With node version 16.20.2 and 18.20.0 Version
Getting error while loading web part.
Something went wrong
If the problem persists, contact the site administrator and give them the information in Technical Details.
TECHNICAL DETAILS
ERROR:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
CALL STACK:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2c53ba84cf3bfb5b03ee8ea1e276e59f.js:198:10987
at new Promise ()
at e.loadComponent (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2c53ba84cf3bfb5b03ee8ea1e276e59f.js:198:10955)
at https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2c53ba84cf3bfb5b03ee8ea1e276e59f.js:198:13163
at async Promise.all (index 0)
#1. Created new solution by following below article.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part
#2. Installed "@pnp/spfx-property-controls" version "^3.16.0".
#3. Added below line of code to import field number from property control
import { PropertyFieldNumber } from '@pnp/spfx-property-controls/lib/PropertyFieldNumber';
#4. Used PropertyFieldNumber in property pane.

Same issue with 3.17.1. Affects all web parts I've tried so far.
Build tools version:3.18.1
Node version:v20.12.1
